# Automatically check the option "Enable stock management at product level" on product creation

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

We have a peculiar WooCommerce setup where each product is only sold once. So we set each product to have 1 stock on creation automatically.

Using stock management feature in WooCommerce requires an option: "Enable stock management at product level" with a checkbox to be "checked"

Is there a function or anything I can use to make this box "checked automatically" upon product creation?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set default values of a new post, you can try this code :

```
$postType = "product";

add_action("save_post_" . $postType, function ($post_ID, \WP_Post $post, $update) {

    if (!$update) {

        // default values for new products

        update_post_meta($post->ID, "_manage_stock", "yes");
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "_stock", 1);


        return;

    }


    // here, operations for updated products


}, 10, 3);
```