# How do I change the initial quantity of a product in woocommerce?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

By default, the product quantity is always "1" when viewing a product page. There doesn't seem an out-of-the-box option to set a different quantity value upon visit, and I don't know what hook or function to look for.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: to change defaults value of a new product, look this : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291992/automatically-check-the-option-enable-stock-management-at-product-level-on-pro/292050#292050

Comment: Barn2 have recently released the [WooCommerce Default Quantity plugin](https://barn2.co.uk/wordpress-plugins/woocommerce-default-quantity/) which can help with this!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `woocommerce_quantity_input_args` filter:

```
function wpse_292293_quantity_input_default( $args, $product ) {
    $args['input_value'] = 2;

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'wpse_292293_quantity_input_default', 10, 2 );
```

When the quantity input is output, it's output with the `woocommerce_quantity_input()` function. This function accepts several arguments including the default value for the input. This filter lets you replace values in the arguments across all uses of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Using this code you can easy to set update quantity . qty box. i was also try this method
it's working fine for me ...I hope it's also helpful thank you :)

```
function wpse_292293_quantity_input_default( $args, $product ) {


$productID = $product->id;

foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $item ){
    
    if( $item['product_id'] == $productID ){    
        $args['input_value'] = $item['quantity'];   
        return $args;       
    }
    
} 

$args['input_value'] = 1;
return $args;

}
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'wpse_292293_quantity_input_default', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a beautiful example in WooCommerce docs
the example even includes a conditional amount.

```
/**
 * Adjust the quantity input values
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 ); // Simple products

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        $args['input_value']    = 2;    // Starting value (we only want to affect product pages, not cart)
    }
    $args['max_value']  = 80;   // Maximum value
    $args['min_value']  = 2;    // Minimum value
    $args['step']       = 2;    // Quantity steps
    return $args;
}
```

Ref:
https://woocommerce.com/document/adjust-the-quantity-input-values/

what you really need to set is the 'input_value' (meaning quantity) value. you have to change the min / max value or step values.. those control the actually input values.